# JPA and non-primitive ElementCollection

Tags: java, jpa

I've got two tables in my database that look like this, with a foreign key from `job_label.job_id` to equivalent column in `job_record`.  Additionally, the triple of `job_id`, `label_key`, and `label` in `job_record` has a unique constraint.

```
mysql> select * from job_record;
+--------+---------+
| job_id | state   |
+--------+---------+
|      1 | success |
|      2 | running |
|      3 | errored |
|      4 | success |
+--------+---------+

mysql> select * from job_label
+--------+-----------+--------+
| job_id | label_key | label  |
+--------+-----------+--------+
|      1 | name      | job 1  |
|      1 | type      | normal |
+--------+-----------+--------+
```

On the Java class side I have this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "job_record")
public class JobRecord {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "job_id")
    private String jobId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "state")
    private JobState state;
}
```

I've tried to define a class for `job_label` that looks something like this:

```
public class JobLabelRecord {
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "label_key")
    private JobLabelKey key;

    @Column(name = "label")
    private String label;
}
```

And then I want a field in `JobRecord` that provides me all labels for that Job as a `List<JobLabelRecord>`.  However, nothing I've tried works.

I've tried declaring `JobLabelRecord` as `Embeddable` with the equivalent field in `JobRecord` as `Embedded`.  I've tried using `ManyToOne` and `OneToMany` mappings, but that fails because there's no `Id` columns in `JobLabelRecord` (and nothing I do with those works correctly).

Am I supposed to be using an `ElementCollection` here instead?  I've tried that as well, but without success.

Any ideas here?  Thanks!

Comment: Nit: `job_label` should has its id column, I hope you have not defined it as `job_id`.

Comment: If I may ask, why you don't have an id column in `job_label`?

Comment: We don't have IDs (i.e. Auto Increment) in `job_label` because we never need to just find the labels.  They aren't indexed for any particular reason.  We do want all labels for a given job, or all labels of a given type, but we don't really need the label whose ID is 529, and nobody will ever see that ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a simple example for this by searching for "jpa elementcollection separate table", such as [JPA Tutorial - JPA ElementCollection CollectionTable Override Example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JPA/0340__JPA_ElementCollection_CollectionTable_Override.htm). Applying this example to your problem gives the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "job_record")
public class JobRecord {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "job_id")
    private Integer jobId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "state")
    private JobState state;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="job_label",
           joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="job_id")) 
    private List<JobLabelRecord> labels;
...

@Embeddable
public class JobLabelRecord {
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "label_key")
    private JobLabelKey key;

    @Column(name = "label")
    private String label;
...
```

Note also the `JobRecord` id should probably be an `Integer`.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow, but I thought I hit a SqlNode-related error when I tried something close to this.

Comment: And the ID in `jobRecord` is a String because they are GUIDs.  That part of the schema already exists, and I don't see me changing that here.

Comment: This worked.  I had tried this (or something very close) before, but kept getting SqlNode-related errors.  Here those are due to code I didn't see that's using a CriteriaBuilder to extract data, but I've changed a table definition and so that code is now failing.  Unrelated to the JPA changes I wanted, so your input is all good.